# Determine which music-on-hold file asterisk is currently playing

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 11.3.0 and am using the default moh, playing at random.

a.) Is there a way to know name moh file Asterisk is currently playing at any point in time ?

b.) My goal is store the file names to a string variable for my CDR,  (e.g) fileNames = file1 - file2 - file3.  My CDR table should have a field:  "fileNames"

Answer (score 0):

There are no way do that exactly, but it is possible catch events via AMI/Asterisk events. StartHold event will have class attached.